# Restarting a log4net memory appender after calling Shutdown()

Tags: c#, logging, .net-4.0, log4net, appender

My application uses several appenders -- a `FileAppender`, `MemoryAppender`, and `AdoNetAppender`.  I have a command to reset the log so that a new file gets created on demand.  This works great -- I simply call `log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().Shutdown()`.

I also log simultaneously to the `MemoryAppender`, and I have a timer that pulls events out of the appender and displays them in a log window.  When I use the aforementioned reset function, the log window stops displaying messages because no more events are being logged.

For the `FileAppender`, I was able to get it to start logging again by calling `ActivateOptions` after setting a proper filename.  I have called `ActivateOptions` on the `MemoryAppender`, but that doesn't get it to start logging again.  Before calling `ActivateOptions`, I have looked at the object to ensure that it is already configured.  It actually preserves the configuration from the time I called the reset function, so that seems okay.

I have also searched online, and people have said that you just have to call `log4net.Config.DOMConfigurator.Configure` (deprecated -- now it is log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure`), but that didn't work, either.

Is there another method I can try to shutdown / restart logging, while supporting File, Memory, and Ado appenders?

Comment: When you say "reset the log" are you just wanting the file to be cleared to empty?

Comment: I want a new file to be created... but I have the FileAppender working just fine.  It's the MemoryAppender that doesn't seem to log any events after I call Shutdown and try to restart with ActivateOptions.

Comment: I should also add that the AdoNetAppender works as well.  To implement that, I call Shutdown, then rename the s3db file, then copy over a new "starting" s3db file with the original filename.  The funny thing is that for the AdoNetAppender, I don't call ActivateOptions anywhere -- it just magically works somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get what you want by not calling the `Shutdown` method. Simply set a new file name on your appender and call `ActivateOptions`. This will close the old log file and open the new one...

Comment: I keep changing my comment here...  :)  Ok, I will give that suggestion a try.  Hopefully it will also work for the AdoNetAppender.

Comment: thanks!  This totally did the trick.  I no longer call Shutdown when resetting the logs, and the MemoryAppender works.  I just change the filename and call ActivateOptions for the FileAppender.  And for the AdoNetAppenders, I call Close() on them, move the old s3db file, and then call ActivateOptions and a new log database is generated.  Perfect!